# Как определить "сработавший" элемент списка и передать его имя в другую функцию?

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть функция проверки, которая через просмотр списка срабатывает на любом (каждом) имеющимся текстовом поле этого списка при потере фокуса. Нужно определить на каком текстовом поле сработал цикл и передать имя этого текстового поля в другую функцию. Как вариант можно спарсить?
Мой код

```
listOfDates = listOf(date1, date2, date3, date4)
listOfDates.forEach {
    i -> i.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
    if(!hasFocus)
        correctDate()
    }
}

fun correctDate() {
    <date1/date2/date3/date4>.setText("Введите данные")
```

Здесь рассматривался аналогичный вопрос - https://qna.habr.com/q/306910

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в OnFocusChangeListener первый параметр - это view, на котором произошло событие (у вас это `_`  перед hasFocus )

Comment: заменил _ на переменную currView через `public lateinit var currView: EditText`. Но в OnFocusChangeListener ошибка что переменная currView  нигде не используется. Хотя `fun correctDate() { currView.setText("Введите данные")` без ошибок